# Where is the MonoDevelop "Application Output" tab?

Tags: monodevelop

I've just created a console application. If I run it from the command line, no problem - I can see my output. But if I run from within MonoDevelop, no application output window appears.

I restarted MonoDevelop and that had no effect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What operating system and what version of MonoDevelop are you using?

Comment: Windows XP SP2 and MonoDevelop 2.4

Comment: This happened to me too. Application Output window just gone, and nowhere to be found in the windows/views menus. This question was the top Google hit on "monodevelop application output window" and I'm still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 10):

And the answer is somewhat illogical (hence why multiple people have this question).
In the Options for the project, on the Run tab, there is a checkbox for "Run on external console." If this option is cleared, the Application Output window will come back when you run the project, and will the become available from the View -> Pads submenu.

Comment: And if the option "Run on external console" is not clear, do we actually have the chance to see anywhere the console? I made a sample program that prints a character at a time and it takes 100 seconds to complete. Yet, I can't see anywhere the output if I don't clear the checkbox. I would have expected to see a new console somewhere.